# How to use capybara in rspec to click on a dropdown option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, capybara, logout

I am using ruby on rails 3.2.3 and capybara to help creating request spec. My goal is to create a spec request that test the log out. The web page:

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Welcome <%= current_user.first_name + " "+ current_user.last_name%>
    <b class="caret"></b>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <a href="#">
      <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete%>
    </a>
  </ul>
</li>
```

For the test, I have

```
describe "sign out" do
  it "should let user to sign out" do
    login_as user, :scope => :user
    # click_on "Welcome #{user.first_name} #{user.last_name}"
    # Now click on Sign out
  end
end
```

I don't know how to click on the Sign out using capybara because it is in a drop down menu, therefore not visible on page. Does anyone know ?

Is there any other way to click on an element in a dropdown menu ?

Comment: I have resolve the same issue (on Twitter Bootstrap button drop down menu) by select the specific link tag:

`find('a', :text => option_title).click`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hello I figured it out eventually. I had to use `xpath` to find the link. Based on the `html` above, here is what I did:

In rspec, I wrote:

```
page.find(:xpath, "//a[@href='/users/sign_out']").click
```

The reason I use "//a[@href='/users/sign_out']" is because the `link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete` is compiled to `<a href="/users/sign_out" ...` on the web page.

And it works :-)

Oh by the way, I found this useful link: http://www.suffix.be/blog/click_image_in_link_capybara

Comment: I've been able to test a very similar dropdown just by doing two clicks, one to open the dropdown and one to click the link.

Comment: That's what I thought too. Can you post some code ? It would be great if that can be applied to the html above. Thanks.

Comment: I believe the missing piece here is enabling Javascript for the request spec; usually capybara-webkit (https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit). Once this is enabled, then the clicks will work as your browser has them work.

Comment: Hi, this way it actually works (the test is able to click) without enabling js.

Comment: Finding via xpath gives you a lot more control than the `click_link` method referenced in these answers. This should have more up votes!

Answer (score 8):

I've tested a dropdown just by clicking both links

```
click_link "Welcome #{current_user.first_name} #{current_user.last_name}"
click_link 'sub link'
```

Comment: How do you click_link "dropdown link".

Comment: You of course may have to replace the variable current_user with the user object created for your test

Comment: Try running it with a JavaScript driver so you can see what is happening. I copied that directly out of my own project.

Comment: I don't get it. How to "run with a javascript driver". Sorry if my question is bad.

thank you

Comment: Change `it "my example" do` to `it "my example", js: true do`By default this will launch Firefox and run the example with selenium, so you can see it run. You might add a sleep to the end so you have time to take in what is happening

Comment: OK that make sense. I install selenium and tried but got error like this:   expected there to be content "Welcome First Last" in "Internal Server Error\nSQLite3::BusyException: cannot rollback transaction - SQL statements in progress: rollback transaction\nWEBrick/1.3.1

Comment: So when selenium launch firefox, it got the content "Internal Server Error\nSQLite3::BusyException: cannot rollback transaction - SQL statements in progress: rollback transaction\nWEBrick/1.3.1

Answer (score 4):

A much easier solution is simply this:

select("option you want to select from menu", :from => "label name")

NOTE:  The "label name" is the actual text of the `<label>`.  However, you can also use the "id" or "name" attribute of the `<select>` here as well, which I think is better since you may change the label text at some point and if you do, your tests will still pass.

Comment: "select" does not work for non-html select box elements. Question is about "button drop down menu" (like twitter bootsrap one) which is not html select box.

Comment: This answer actually addresses the title of the question. I guess that's why it has the most votes.

Comment: The code isn't a select, it's bootstrap's logout code. So select won't work

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, but my dropdown didn't have any text, only icons:

```haml
%li#user-menu.dropdown
  %a.dropdown-toggle{ href: "#", data: { toggle: "dropdown" }, role: "button", aria: { haspopup: "true", expanded: "false" } }
    %i.fa.fa-user
    %span.caret
  %ul.dropdown-menu
    %li.logout-text= link_to "Log Out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete
```

In my spec I used:

```ruby
def when_I_sign_out
  find('#user-menu').click
  click_on 'Log Out'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

My example for this

```
find("ol.nya-bs-select.btn-default.form-control[ng-model='scope.values.countries']")
    .find_button("Nothing selected").click
```